# Change floating action button color on press

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I want to use the floating action button as some sort of a favorite button, i.e. a bookmark function. I am using a `boolean`, initialized like so:

```
boolean favSelected = false;
```

and my activity will retrieve some information from my SQLite database to determine whether `favSelected` will be true or false. If it's true, I would want my fab to be in a different color, and if false the original color. I tried this:

```
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(favSelected = false) {
                favSelected = true;
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{0}}, new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.header_pressed)}));
            } else if ( favSelected = true){
                favSelected = false;
                fab.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{0}}, new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)}));
            }

        }
    });
```

but it didn't work. The intended function is a bit like a checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `if(favSelected = false)`  This is assignment to favSelected, Please use as if`(favSelected == false)`.

For comparisons we use `==`  sign instead of `=`

so Modify your code like this

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!favSelected) {
                    favSelected = true;
                    view.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]
                            {new int[]{0}}, new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)}));
                } else if (favSelected) {
                    favSelected = false;
                    view.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{0}}, new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)}));
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to change your FAB color on pressed state:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_pressed}
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_pressed),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_normal),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_pressed),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_normal)
    };
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```