# After clicking the FloatingActionButton, the button maintains the same color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I can successfully set the color of the FloatingActionButton in androidmanifest.xml, but I want to use the program to control the color change, but it has no effect

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        public void startDetect(){
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if(useDetect == false){
                default_color = btnClick2detect.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor();
                btnClick2detect.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.red));
                //btnClick2detect.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
                //btnClick2detect.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
                //btnClick2detect.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.tfe_color_primary));
                useDetect = true;
            }
            else if(useDetect == true){
                //btnClick2detect.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(default_color));
                useDetect = false;
            }
            intent.putExtra(KEY_USE_DETECT, useDetect);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    
            restartWith(intent);
        }
```

Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: First of all you don't change in `androidmanifest.xml` you change in layout . Second `ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.red)` should be `ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))` .

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356876/6514945

Comment: @ ADM  
Thank you for your answer, I have solved the problem